# Adding int to long

Tags: c++, recursion, vector, long-integer

I am creating a recursive formula to add up all the elements in a `vector`. The problem them I'm having is that my result is not adding to the `vector` results so it always returns `0`. I have tried `static_cast` to turn it into an `int` but I'm still not able to figure it out. Here's my code:

```
long vectorSum(const std::vector<int>& data, unsigned int position) {
int ret = 0;
if(position == data.size()-1) {
      return ret;
  } else {
      ret += data[position];
      return vectorSum(data, position+1);
  }
}
```

I am calling the function like this:

```
std::vector<int> test1;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    test1.push_back(i);
}
cout << vectorSum(test1, 0) << "\n";
```

Comment: `int ret = 0;` + `return ret;` or `return vectorSum(data, position+1);` == 0. In other words: you are not accumulating the results.

Comment: [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) springs to mind for some weird reason ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct:

```
ret += data[position];
return vectorSum(data, position+1);
```

The new value of ret (`+= data[position]`) isn't being used anywhere or passed back to the caller.

Remeber: `ret` is strictly local to each invocation of `vectorSum()`.  It doesn't exist outside of your vectorSum(); it's being set to "0" every time you invoke vectorSum().

Answer (score 0):

Normally, one *adds to* the value of a recursive call. You are not doing that. In your code, it will keep calling with a modified `position` until it hits the terminating condition, then that `return 0;` goes all the way back up to the caller.

```
long vectorSum(const std::vector<int>& data, unsigned int position) {
    int ret = 0;
    if(position == data.size()-1) {
        return ret;
    } else {
        ret += data[position]; //this line has no affect on the result!

        return vectorSum(data, position+1); //you don't accumulate anything
                                            //this will always return 0
    }
}
```

Instead, you want to add the current value plus the value from the recursive call:

```
long vectorSum(const std::vector<int>& data, unsigned int position) {
    if(position == data.size()-1) {
        //terminating condition, return 0
        return 0;
    } else {
        //add current value plus value from processing the rest of the list
        return data[position] + vectorSum(data, position+1);
    }
}
```

*As a side note:* recursion is a great tool, but it can easily be misused by applying it to problems that already have better and more elegant solutions. For this, something like [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) would probably be the most "natural" solution for C++.

Comment: But note that it's no longer tail-recursive.

Comment: True, but I don't know that they were trying for that. This *works*. What is the *best* is probably not using recursion at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
long vectorSum(const std::vector<int>& data, unsigned int position) { 
if(position == data.size())
   return 0; 
else
    return data[position]+vectorSum(data, position+1);
}
```

Then call it as 
int sum=vectorSum(data,0);

Comment: Be aware that when you use position==data.size()-1 you are skipping one value so you should either remove -1 or put return data[data.size()-1] instead of return 0;